# How would I load a new page in JavaFX WebView by an event from another method?

Tags: java, javafx

Basically, I am trying to call the equivalent of the line:

```
myWebView.getEngine().load("http://google.com");
```

I want to call this line by an interaction from a listener that is networked to touch controls on my phone. My listener can call methods easily. My only problem is that modifying the WebView at all from other methods is proving difficult. The WebView can't be modified from any other method but the one it was instantiated in, it also doesn't work to make it a public WebView. I'm getting errors with every workaround I've tried, including a PageHandler class. All I want to do is call that line of code whenever my listener (in another method) is called.

I'm sure there is a very simple solution to this that I'm missing, and I welcome you guys's help.

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Can't you expose a public method which accepts a `url` and loads it into the `WebEngine`?

Comment: How would I choose when to do that load? Which I would like to do based on the time the touch interaction happens

Comment: Touch Interaction must involve `Button` press or some other event. Just call the method on its ActionEvent.

Comment: The touch interaction is from a networked listener connected to my phone. It doesn't involve a button. The application is on my computer. The problem is that I can't load the URL from another method successfully.